# App API design advice specifically around security

Tags: javascript, api, rest, security, encryption

I'm building an app and would like some feedback on my approach to building the data sync process and API that supports it. For context, these are the guiding principles for my app/API:

- Free: I do not want to charge people at all to use the app/API.
- Open source: the source code for both the app and API are available to the public to use as they wish.
- Decentralised: the API service that supports the app can be run by anyone on any server, and made available for use to users of the app.
- Anonymous: the user should not have to sign up for the service, or submit any personal identifying information that will be stored alongside their data.
- Secure: the user's data should be encrypted before being sent to the server, anyone with access to the server should have no ability to read the user's data.

I will implement an instance of the API on a public server which will be selected in the app by default. That way initial users of the app can sync their data straight away without needing to find or set up an instance of the API service. Over time, if the app is popular then users will hopefully set up other instances of the API service either for themselves or to make available to other users of the app should they wish to use a different instance (or if the primary instance runs out of space, goes down, etc). They may even access the API in their own apps. Essentially, I want them to be able to have the choice to be self sufficient and not have to necessarily rely on other's providing an instance on the service for them, for reasons of privacy, resilience, cost-saving, etc. Note: the data in question is not sensitive (i.e. financial, etc), but it is personal.

The user's sync journey works like this:

1. User downloads the app, and creates their data in the process of using the app.
2. When the user is ready to initially sync, they enter a "password" in the password field, which is used to create a complex key with which to encrypt their data. Their password is stored locally in plain text but is never sent to the server.
3. User clicks the "Sync" button, their data is encrypted (using their password) and sent to the specified (or default) API instance and responds by giving them a unique ID which is saved by the app.
4. For future syncs, their data is encrypted locally using their saved password before being sent to the API along with their unique ID which updates their synced data on the server.
5. When retrieving synced data, their unique ID is sent to the API which responds with their encrypted data. Their locally stored password is then used to decrypt the data for use by the app.

I've implemented the app in javascript, and the API in Node.js (restify) with MongoDB as a backend, so in practice a sync requests to the server looks like this:

**1. Initial sync**

POST /api/data

Post body:

```
{
    "data":"DWCx6wR9ggPqPRrhU4O4oLN5P09onApoAULX4Xt+ckxswtFNH/QQ+Y/RgxdU+8+8/muo4jo/jKnHssSezvjq6aPvYK+EAzAoRmXenAgUwHOjbiAXFqF8gScbbuLRlF0MsTKn/puIyFnvJd..."
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "id":"507f191e810c19729de860ea",
    "lastUpdated":"2016-07-06T12:43:16.866Z"
}
```

**2. Get sync data**

GET /api/data/507f191e810c19729de860ea

Response:

```
{
    "data":"DWCx6wR9ggPqPRrhU4O4oLN5P09onApoAULX4Xt+ckxswtFNH/QQ+Y/RgxdU+8+8/muo4jo/jKnHssSezvjq6aPvYK+EAzAoRmXenAgUwHOjbiAXFqF8gScbbuLRlF0MsTKn/puIyFnvJd...",
    "lastUpdated":"2016-07-06T12:43:16.866Z"
}
```

**3. Update synced data**

POST /api/data/507f191e810c19729de860ea

Post body:

```
{
    "data":"DWCx6wR9ggPqPRrhU4O4oLN5P09onApoAULX4Xt+ckxswtFNH/QQ+Y/RgxdU+8+8/muo4jo/jKnHssSezvjq6aPvYK+EAzAoRmXenAgUwHOjbiAXFqF8gScbbuLRlF0MsTKn/puIyFnvJd..."
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "lastUpdated":"2016-07-06T13:21:23.837Z"
}
```

Their data in MongoDB will look like this:

```
{
    "id":"507f191e810c19729de860ea",
    "data":"DWCx6wR9ggPqPRrhU4O4oLN5P09onApoAULX4Xt+ckxswtFNH/QQ+Y/RgxdU+8+8/muo4jo/jKnHssSezvjq6aPvYK+EAzAoRmXenAgUwHOjbiAXFqF8gScbbuLRlF0MsTKn/puIyFnvJd...",
    "lastUpdated":"2016-07-06T13:21:23.837Z"
}
```

Encryption is currently implemented using CryptoJS's AES implementation. As the app provides the user's password as a passphrase to the AES "encrypt" function, it generates a 256-bit key which which to encrypt the user's data, before being sent to the API.

That about sums up the sync process, it's fairly simple but obviously it needs to be secure and reliable. My concerns are:

- As the MongoDB ObjectID is fairly easy to guess, it is possible that a malicious user could request someone else's data (as per step 2. Get sync data) by guessing their ID. However, if they are successful they will only retrieve encrypted data and will not have the key with which to decrypt it. The same applies for anyone who has access to the database on the server.
- Given the above, is the CryptoJS AES implementation secure enough so that in the real possibility that a user's encrypted data is retrieved by a malicious user, they will not realistically be able to decrypt the data?
- Since the API is open to anyone and doesn't audit or check the submitted data, anyone could potentially submit any data they wish to be stored in the service, for example:

Post body:

```
{
    "data":"This is my anyold data..."
}
```

Is there anything practical I can do to guard against this whilst adhering to the guiding principles above?

- General abuse of the service such as users spamming initial syncs (step 1 above) over and over to fill up the space on the server; or some user's using disproportionately large amounts of server space. I've implemented some features to guard against this, such as logging IPs for initial syncs for one day (not kept any longer than that) in order to limit a single IP to a set number of initial syncs per day. Also I'm limiting the post body size for syncs. These options are configurable in the API however, so if a user doesn't like these limitations on a public API instance, they can host their own instance and tweak the settings to their liking.

So that's it, I would appreciate anyone who has any thoughts or feedback regarding this approach given my guiding principles. I couldn't find any examples where other apps have attempted a similar approach, so if anyone knows of any and can link to them I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really comment on whether specific AES algorithms/keys are secure or not, but assuming they are (and the keys are generated properly), it should not be a problem if other users can access the encrypted data.

You can maybe protect against abuse, without requiring other accounts, by using captchas or similar guards against automatic usage. If you require a catcha on new accounts, and set limits to all accounts on data volume and call frequency, you should be ok.

To guard against accidental clear-text data, you might generate a secondary key for each account, and then check on the server with the public secondary key whether the messages can be decrypted. Something like this:

```
data = secondary_key(user_private_key(cleartext))
```

This way the data will always be encrypted, and in worst case the server will be able to read it, but others wouldn't.

A few comments to your API :) If you're already using HTTP and POST, you don't really need an `id`. The `POST` usually returns a `URI` that points to the created data. You can then `GET` that `URI`, or `PUT` it to change:

```
POST /api/data
{"data": "..."}
```

Response:

```
Location: /api/data/12345
{"data": "...", "lastmodified": "..." }
```

To change it:

```
PUT /api/data/12345
{"data": "..."}
```

You don't have to do it this way, but it might be easier to implement on the client side, and maybe even help with caching and cache invalidation.

Comment: Many thanks for the useful suggestions Robert, and for taking the time to answer.